# Robot Framework: For loop contains no keywords

Tags: python, robotframework

I"m using robot framework 3.0.1 but there is for loop contains no keywords error display.

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          ../Resources/Generic/common_resource.txt
Resource          ../Resources/Generic/generic_variables.txt

*** Variables ***
@{listBrowser}  firefox    chrome

*** Test Cases ***
PhpTravels_Net
    [Setup]
    :FOR  ${browser}  IN   @{listBrowser}
    \ Open Browser  https://www.google.com.my  ${browser}
    \ Log  ${browser}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You need two or more spaces after the `\`.